# send multiple messages from TCP server to Client(C sharp to Android)

Tags: c#, android, sockets, tcpclient, tcplistener

I am developing an app, in which c sharp server communicates with android client.
Server needs to send multiple message to the Android tcpClient. As to send message I have to close the tcpClient Object on the server. otherwise it does not send. Once tcpClient is closed how can i communicate with my client again , how can i keep track and send multiple messages, once i close tcpClient, or there is any other way of sending without closing it.
If the question is still unclear, please comment below

it sends one message easlity but i need to send more messages from time to time

Here is the snippet of code for server

```
//in a thread
void receivingMessages(object param)
    {
        try
        {
            var paramArray = (object[])param;
            var id = paramArray[0];
            var client = paramArray[1] as TcpClient;

            var stream = client.GetStream();

            while (true)
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
                int bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 2048);

                if (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    string v = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);

                    int index = v.IndexOf('\0');
                    string trimmedXml = v.TrimEnd(new char[] { '\0' });

                    var root = XDocument.Parse(trimmedXml).Root;
                    //to get the type of xml like it is login register or message
                    string xmlType = root.Name.ToString();

                    //some checks     
                    string result = " server messages";
                    SendMessage(client, result);

                }

                //Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }

    }


    public void SendMessage(TcpClient client, string message)
    {

        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
        stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        client.Close();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void SendMessage(TcpClient client, string message)
{

    //byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
    writer.WriteLine(message);
    writer.Flush();

}
```

Comment: @L.B It sounds to me like he hadn't been able to send the message without closing the stream, but he wants to keep it open: "is there any way of sending without closing..."  so I rewrote it to write the message, without closing.

Comment: @0_______0 still not able to send message, unless i close it tcpclient

Comment: @mindFreezer Maybe try setting `client.NoDelay=true;` in the SendMessage method, I tested my code and it worked fine so I'm not sure what is wrong.

Comment: @0_______0 hmmm, i will give it a try, then will let u know

Comment: didn't work this way either, now i send a response to server after every message so server will surely have tcpclient to send to ...

Comment: @0_______0didn't work this way either, now i send a response to server after every message so server will surely have tcpclient to send to ...

Comment: @mindFreezer I can't replicate your problem, I copied your code, and aside from the XML bit, my modified `SendMessage` function worked for me. I would suggest debugging the code to see what happens when that function is called, and use something like WireShark to see what is happening on the network, if/when anything is sent.

Comment: @0_______0 okay i will try this too, i have experience working on sockets/tcpclient before too, there wasn't any problem in my last project between both C# client/server on lan on windows, now client android on mac, server c# on windows, could this be the problem , but as far I know tcp protocols are same everywhere

Comment: I tried the same , it is working perfect, make sure to pass the correct TcpClient object , then set a timer to receive data if available. let me know if you need the sample